# Matrix multiplication performance improvement

Tags: matrix, data-structures, matrix-multiplication

I have got some unclear questions for the following matrix multiplication algorithm.

[image]

1) Why does the inner for-loop (line 6) do not use a “parallel for” construct?

2) Can we further improve the performance of the inner loop computation (lines 6-7) by some form of parallelism?

Comment: Those questions seem perfectly clear. Where are the unclear questions you claim to have?

Comment: Clarify (1): Are you wondering why both 5 and 6 are not parallel, or why it is not the case that 6 is parallel and 5 is not?

Comment: I need to know why both 5 and 6 are not parallel

Comment: Line 6 and 7 implement a reduction, it could be parallel but it would have more overhead (it requires communication) than a parallel map which is what the other two loops are. Also it's parallel enough already.